# HAXM installation failing on azure

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, intel-haxm

While installing Android studio on windows 10, Azure machine.
I am getting below error.

```
Unable to install Intel HAXM
HAXM doesn't support nested virtual machines.
Unfortunately, the Android Emulator can't support virtual machine acceleration from within a virtual machine.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Start the emulator on a non-virtualized operating system
 3) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)
```

I understood,it is mentioned to use a physical machine.
But, is there any option we need to enable on Azure (or even on AWS, I will switch to that if it is working on it).?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has the answer, i.e. "HAXM doesn't support nested virtual machines".
Intel HAXM is an optimized hypervisor for certain set of intel processors, mean to run the Android VM.
Azure is a public cloud Infrastructure-as-a-Service which gives users Virtual Machines to run their workloads on. So by trying to install HAXM on a VM running on Azure, you are trying to run a virtual-machine within a virtual-machine, which is what is called "nested virtual machines".

While it is not impossible to run nested virtual machines, but not for HAXM. As far as I know, HAXM will probably not run for the same reasons also on AWS or GCP either.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood,it is mentioned to use a physical machine. But, is there any option we need to enable on Azure?

What you want is not possible.  HAXM does not work within a nested virtual machine.  You will be unable to run HAXM within a Azure or AWS VM.

**HAXM and Android Studio cannot be ran within a virtual machine at this time.**