# Nested virtualization on AMD Ryzen with host Linux, guest Windows

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I have host Ubuntu 18 with QEMU KVM.
Virtual Machine Windows 10 (hyper-v enabled)

I want to run Android Studio emulator on Windows VM.

On host I have kvm_amd nested=1

VM settings #1:

```
<vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>

<cpu mode='host-model' check='partial'>
  <model fallback='allow'/>
  <feature policy='disable' name='hypervisor'/>
</cpu>
```

with this settings Windows VM has:

- Virtualization in Firmaware: Yes
- VM Monitor Mode extension: No

VM Settings #2:

```
<vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'/>
```

with this settings VM has:

- Virtualization in Firmaware: Yes
- VM Monitor Mode extension: Yes
- but VM is very slow, can't work on it
- if i change topology to something else than default, VM get into boot loop

Please, let me know if additional information would be needed.
Could you help me ?

Comment: Android studio doesn’t support being ran from within a VM[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1435409/haxm-installation-failing-on-azure/1435419#1435419)

Comment: Which VM is slow and what do you define as slow? What hardware does the VM have available?

Comment: My hardware: Ryzen 5 and 16 GB RAM + SSD disk
I said slow, because without host-passthrough VM run much faster

Comment: And you can just run Android Studio on Linux anyway. That said, even with hardware acceleration, nested virtualization has a noticeable performance penalty.

Comment: Yes, but i cant set topology manually. I read that this should help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got qemu-kvm working with a Windows 11 Professional client with Hyper-V and Docker Desktop running smoothly.

This is my setup, maybe it helps others. NO ADVERTISMENT INTENDED!
Hardware:

```
Gigabyte X570 I AORUS PRO WIFI
BIOS-Version F37a (Virtualization enabled, Hyperthreading disabled)
AMD Ryzen 9 3950X 16-Core Processor
64Gb RAM
```

Software:

```
OS: Centos Stream 8
Kernel: 4.18.0-448.el8.x86_64
libvirt 8.0.0
QEMU 6.2.0
```

/etc/modprobe.d/kvm.conf

```
options kvm ignore_msrs=1
options kvm_amd nested=1
```

virsh settings:

```
<memory unit='KiB'>16777216</memory>
<currentMemory unit='KiB'>16777216</currentMemory>
<vcpu placement='static'>12</vcpu>
<resource>
  <partition>/machine</partition>
</resource>
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-rhel8.2.0'>hvm</type>
</os>
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <hyperv mode='custom'>
    <relaxed state='on'/>
    <vapic state='on'/>
    <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    <vpindex state='on'/>
    <runtime state='on'/>
    <synic state='on'/>
    <stimer state='on'/>
    <reset state='on'/>
    <vendor_id state='on' value='1234567890ab'/>
    <frequencies state='on'/>
    <reenlightenment state='on'/>
    <tlbflush state='on'/>
    <ipi state='on'/>
    <evmcs state='off'/>
  </hyperv>
  <kvm>
    <hidden state='on'/>
    <hint-dedicated state='on'/>
    <poll-control state='on'/> 
  </kvm>
  <vmport state='off'/>
  <smm state='on'/>
</features>
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none' migratable='off'>
  <topology sockets='1' dies='1' cores='12' threads='1'/>
  <cache mode='passthrough'/>
  <feature policy='require' name='topoext'/>
  <feature policy='require' name='svm'/>
  <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
  <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
  <feature policy='require' name='invtsc'/>
</cpu>
<clock offset='localtime'>
  <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
  <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
  <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  <timer name='tsc' present='yes' mode='native'/>
</clock>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
<pm>
  <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
  <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
</pm>
```

I installed Windows 11 Pro without SecureBoot and TPM. Google details pls.

```
Shift+F10 to launch cmd in windows setup regedit goto “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup” 
right-click “New ⇒ Key ⇒ LabConfig” “New ⇒ DWORD (32-bit) ⇒ 
BypassTPMCheck ⇒ 1” same for “BypassRAMCheck” and “BypassSecureBootCheck”
```